# My monitor won't stay on for more than a split second

Tags: display

When I plug in my I-INC if171a, the backlight turns on for a split second then I get no response from the power button or anything. I have to unplug it then plug it in again to see the backlight for that split second.

The monitor suddenly shut off when I was browsing the web and now I have this problem.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is what happens when a CCFL backlight is failing. Replace your backlight.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the power LED doesn't light up at all. I'm using the same power cord and VGA cord to connect to this monitor I'm tying on as I am to connect the faulty one.

Comment: @c00lryguy It could also be a failing power supply on your monitor. Perhaps [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).

Comment: This is what I'm guessing. I'm going to test the capacitors on the power supply of the monitor tomorrow.